# how do you alter queries for node/# to select entity-referenced node titles instead of just target_id?

Tags: 7, entities, services, database, nodes

I am using Drupal 7 Services and the generic call of `services/node/#`. Unfortunately that only gives me the target_id as a property of every field with type `entity reference`; and my interface does need the node title at the least.

I have...

```
function  HOOK_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
    if ($query->hasTag('NODE RETRIEVE')) { // WHAT TAG SHOULD I USE?
        // ..TO ONLY ALTER (service)/NODE/# QUERIES?
    }        
    $fields =& $query->getFields();
    ... // AND HOW DO I ALTER TO GET REFERENCED FIELD NODE TITLES?
}
```

All said, I do realize I might be able to use node_load and loop over the results to run subsequent queries for this data, but that seems kind of expensive, unless the resulting hook_alter_query would be too complicated. Please say so if you feel that's most likely the case.

Comment: Sorry @Eli, browser is misbehaving :) You'll need to add another join to pull in a second copy of the node table (joined on the target_id column from the er field's data table), and then the revision table to (safely) get the title. Might be easier to grab the nids and use `node_load_multiple()`

Comment: @Clive, regarding joins, where would i `addTag` or how would I only do that for `service/node/#` ?

Comment: I don't know what specific tags (if any) that query would have. Best to use the Devel module to inspect the query and have a look

Comment: @Clive, can you speak to the join and how to get that joined field's node's title then? I can `$query->join('field_data_field_airport_arrival_er', 'afs', 'afs.entity_id = base.nid');` but i can't see how to get the node title of the target_id referenced node.

Comment: Something like `$query->join('node', 'n2', 'n2.nid = afs.field_airport_arrival_er_target_id');`, and then add `n2.title` to the queried fields. That's off the top of my head it might need some tweaking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe @Clive was going in this direction here, but I wasn't clear that the Services does in fact invoke `Hook_node_load($nodes, $types)` when using the retrieve methods at `services/node/#`. I suppose I was avoiding the node_load_multiple because they are so heavy for only the few fields I want. Code is below

```
function HOOK_node_load($nodes, $types){
    if (in_array('yournodetype', $types)) {
        foreach($nodes as &$node) {
            $f = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_your_reference_field');
            if (!empty($f) && isset($f[0]['target_id'])) {
                $refNode = _mymodule_reference_load($f[0]['target_id']); // this function simply writes a manual SQL query for my title and iata values.
                $node->field_your_reference_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['title'] = $refNode->title;
                $node->field_your_reference_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['iata'] = $refNode->field_iata[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
            }
        }
    }
}

function _mymodule_reference_load($nid){
    $refNode = db_query(sprintf("SELECT N.nid, N.type, N.title, A.field_iata_value, R1.field_readmore1_value, R2.field_readmore2_value
                FROM node N
                LEFT JOIN field_data_field_iata A ON N.nid = A.entity_id 
                LEFT JOIN field_data_field_readmore1 R1 ON N.nid = R1.entity_id 
                LEFT JOIN field_data_field_readmore2 R2 ON N.nid = R2.entity_id 
                AND A.deleted =  '0'
                AND R1.deleted =  '0'
                AND R2.deleted =  '0'
                WHERE N.nid =  '%s'", $nid))->fetchObject();
    $refNode->field_iata = array('und' => array(0 => array('value' => $refNode->field_iata_value))); // maintain same structure as node_load
    $refNode->field_readmore1 = array('und' => array(0 => array('value' => $refNode->field_readmore1_value)));
    $refNode->field_readmore2 = array('und' => array(0 => array('value' => $refNode->field_readmore2_value)));
    unset($refNode->field_iata_value);
    unset($refNode->field_readmore1_value);
    unset($refNode->field_readmore2_value);
    return $refNode;
}
```